# IBM Bluemix : Will it work for a Spring-MVC ,Postgresql with our domain-name

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, ibm-cloud, domain-name

We wanted to check out [IBM Bluemix](http://www.bluemix.net) which we would like to try out for our Spring-MVC based application. I have personally never worked with IBM Bluemix so I would welcome some assistance.

These are some of the points of the application :

Technologies in the webapp :

```
Spring-MVC, Spring-Security, Maven, Java, JSP, JS, PostgreSQL as DB, HTML, CSS
```

Now, we have domain-name purchased and we would like to register this domain-name with IBM Bluemix, this way, whenver someone pings the domain-name.com, then the webapp on Bluemix is ran. This way we don't have to manage IT infrastructure, which is our main point. **Is this possible?**

If yes, can someone please highlight some steps for me. Thanks a lot. I am posting my Spring-config, in-case if that's necessary.

root-context.xml :

```
  <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev.spring">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
                destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <beans:property name="url"
                        value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:port/db"/>
        <beans:property name="username" value="user"
        <beans:property name="password" value="pass"/>
        <beans:property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
        <beans:property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="20"/>
        <beans:property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.journaldev.spring.model"/>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="cache.use_query_cache">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="loginServiceImpl" class="com.journaldev.spring.Login.LoginServiceImpl"/>
    <beans:bean id="hostLoginServiceImpl" class="com.journaldev.spring.Login.HostLoginService"/>
    <beans:bean id="agencyLoginServiceImpl" class="com.journaldev.spring.Login.AgencyLoginService"/>
    <task:annotation-driven/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

Kindly let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  Please check out this doc [here](http://www.tonyerwin.com/2014/09/bluemix-ui-ssl-certificates-and-custom.html).  You can point your own domain to Bluemix.  If you are running in `us-south` you need an `A` record pointing to `75.126.81.68`.  If you are running in `eu-gb` then you need an `A` record pointing to `5.10.124.142`.

You can also use your own SSL certificate as well.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the application you would like to port, Bluemix allows you to have a lot of solutions to run this kinds of application on the cloud:

- Bluemix liberty runtime running over Cloud Foundry is perfectly compatible with a Spring MVC application
  For this kind of solution you can start from here

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#!starters/liberty/index.html#liberty

- in the case you wish tohave a runtime running on openjdk and tomcat you could use the java Cloud Foundry  buildpack instead of the standard one
- if you wish to have a different solution than runtime you could think about Docker containers on Bluemix, providing a full portable and scalable solution and an higher level of customization than a runtime

www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_index.html

You could create your full custom container or start from a great list containers available on docker hub

- or you could also think about a VM on the cloud based on Openstack, actually in beta version
- you could bind you runtime/container/VM to PostgreSql cloud service on Bluemix

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/PostgreSQL/index.html#PostgreSQL

or to the one offered by Compose on Bluemix